# Are all elements in a POST requests body mandatory?

Tags: ios, http, post, http-post, http-method

If a POST request requires that i send four data elements in the body, like:

```
{
  "name":abc,
  "surname":xyz,
  "contact_no":1234,
  "address":random_value
}
```

What will happen if I miss out some of the elements, for example if I call the web service with elements like,

```
{
  "name":abc,
  "surname":xyz,
}
```

What error is the server likely to throw ? I am having this issue because I am making a API call and it's giving me a HTTP error 500, so I guess it's not an error on my part, but this is one doubt i wanted to clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: its depent up on your backend side declartion ,

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on the service structure (if all fields are mandatory or not),

and HTTP error (500) returns to server error or (server or link) not found .